# Windows pip cp949

Tags: python, encoding, pip

I'm using Windows 10

This error occurs during `pip` installation

It's the pip version
`pip 20.2.1 (python 3.8)`

`pip` is not working

Encoding the python file to `utf-8` does not solve it.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\김민수\Documents\GitHub\Watch-a-movie-N.11-Django> pip install -r .\requirement.txt
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 331, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    skip_reason = self._check_skip_installed(req)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 236, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install.check_if_exists(self.use_user_site)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 432, in check_if_exists
    existing_dist = get_distribution(self.req.name)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 501, in get_distribution
    dist = search_distribution(req_name)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 492, in search_distribution
    packages = get_installed_distributions(skip=())
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 477, in get_installed_distributions
    return [d for d in working_set
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 478, in <listcomp>
    if local_test(d) and
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 386, in dist_is_local
    return is_local(dist_location(dist))
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 566, in dist_location
    egg_link = egg_link_path(dist)
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 542, in egg_link_path
    if not virtualenv_no_global() and user_site:
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 111, in virtualenv_no_global
    return _no_global_under_venv()
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 72, in _no_global_under_venv
    cfg_lines = _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines()
  File "c:\users\김민수\documents\github\watch-a-movie-n.11-django\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 55, in _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines
    return f.read().splitlines()  # avoids trailing newlines
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 18: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve] and provide that. In particular, the requirements.txt file is missing. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What version of Pip are you using? I found [a bug with a very similar traceback](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8717), which [was resolved in Pip 20.2.2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/8718). (BTW, I found that by googling the last internal call in the traceback, `_get_pyvenv_cfg_lines`. Please always try your own research before asking a question. See [ask].)

Comment: Encoding the config file as UTF-8 wouldn't fix it because it's already in UTF-8 (or at least that's what I'm reading). The problem is that CP-949 is being used to decode it, incorrectly.

Comment: I'd try `chcp 65001` _before_ running `pip`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with requirements.txt

Comment: Then you can surely remove it from your question and show what the results are without it, or? Sorry, but that [mcve] part is not just a good suggestion but actually required for a question here.